# Selecting from multiple tables based on the values of columns in one table

Tags: php, postgresql

I am working on using psql to crete dental charts.  I have one table that has a value for each individual. It consists of an id for that person, and 32 additional columns (one for each tooth). These additional columns have numeric values.

In addition, there is a table for each tooth (obviously, 32 columns). Each of these tables has two columns. The first column has a list of numbers equivalent the numbers used in the columns of the first table. The second column has a filename for an image of that particular tooth in a different state (0 --> goodtooth.jpg, 1 --> filling.jpg, etc).

What I am trying to do is generate a query which will take the id from one set of records in the main table, and use the values in each tooth's column to point to the correct image in each tooth's table, thereby generating a dental chart. I've done inner joins to link records across tables, but that's always been using the same id for each table. What do I use when I want to match multiple tables based on discrete values in multiple columns of one table?

I can't get my head around where to start with this one. I've done select statements and gotten my output to display correctly, I've also worked with views when I've been working with many columns across tables. All of those, however, have been with one id that matched the other tables. I'm not sure where to begin where I have to use different ids for different tables.

EDIT. Main table:

`id  | ur8 | ur7 | ur6 | ur5 | ur4 | ur3 | ur2 | ur1 | ul1 | ul2 | ul3 | ul4 | ul5 | ul6 | ul7 | ul8 | lr8 | lr7 | lr6 | lr5 | lr4 | lr3 | lr2 | lr1 | ll1 | ll2 | ll3 | ll4 | ll5 | ll6 | ll7 | ll8 -----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----- 480 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 (1 row)`

32 tables of the same format as below, named corresponding to the columns in the main table

`id |   img ----+--------- 0 | ur8.jpg (1 row)`

There will be additional id values in each table. I figure if I can get it to work with just the one right now, I can get it to work with the additional ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Including the SQL defining the tables would be much better than describing them in prose. From the description, it appears that a union of 32 queries will be required. That complexity is a result of modeling teeth as a repeating group. Consider revising the model to eliminate the repeating group. In addition to helping address the stated problem, modeling teeth as rows in a table also facilitates handling cases of an individual with more than 32 teeth (hyperdontia).

Comment: I'll restate: modeling teeth as a repeating group is a poor design. As you've already discovered, the need to repeat code for each member of the group complicates queries. You state that you can't "get my head around where to start." I strongly suggest redesigning the model to eliminate repeating groups. Consider using a table with three columns: ID, tooth position, and tooth condition.